# unable to call the shell script from java

Tags: java, spring, shell, hadoop, processbuilder

I am calling a shell script from Java using `ProcessBuilder`, but I am not getting any value. It shows an empty result.

Here's my code:

```
package webservice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}/{param2}/{param3}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String bedroom,@PathParam("param2") String bathroom,@PathParam("param3")String area) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/script/spark-submit.sh");  
        pb.environment().put("a", bedroom);
        pb.environment().put("b", bathroom);
        pb.environment().put("c", area);
        Process p=pb.start();
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        int i =0;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while((i=is.read())!=-1)
            sb.append((char)i);
            System.out.println("value of sb:"+sb.toString());
            String a =sb.toString();
            System.out.println("value of a:"+a);
            String[] arr = a.split(" ");
            if (arr != null) 
            {
                System.out.println("predicted value is " + arr[arr.length - 1]);
            }
            String output = "predicted value is " + arr[arr.length - 1];
            return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
        }
    }
```

shell script code

```
spark-submit --class scalatest.scalatest.scalatest --master local[4] /home/ec2-user/scalatest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar $a $b $c
```

Comment: can you show me the content of  spark-submit.sh file

Comment: can you change process builder invocation as follows?String[] command = {"/bin/bash", "/script/spark-submit.sh"};
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(command);

Comment: spark-submit --class scalatest.scalatest.scalatest --master local[4] /home/ec2-user/scalatest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar $a $b $c

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
Process p=pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

it seems like your process never really gets started

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
try {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line = buff.readLine()) != null){
        temp += line;
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
} catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi i was getting process builder exception .error=2 ,  no such file or directory.

Comment: ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/script/spark-submit.sh"); 
 pb.environment().put("a", bedroom);
 pb.environment().put("b", bathroom);
 pb.environment().put("c", area);
 String temp = null;
  try {
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process p = rt.exec(pb.toString());
     p.waitFor();
     BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     String line;
     while((line = buff.readLine()) != null){
         temp += line;
     }
     System.out.println("temp :"+temp);
 } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
 }

Comment: try to give full path of your script